# How to recolor multiple widgets by dragging in Tkinter

Tags: python, widget, tkinter, drag

I'm trying to make a script where there are for example 9 widgets (Buttons, Labels...) and I want when I click and hold on any widget and I drag over another widget, both of widgets to be recolored (resp. all the widgets I dragged over), until I release the mouse button.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def recolor(event):
    global ButtonList
    event.widget.config(bg="red")

    return


ButtonList=["b0","b1","b2","b3","b4","b5","b5","b6","b7","b8"]

i = 0

while i < 9:
    ButtonList[i] = Label(root, text = i, width = 4, height = 2)
    ButtonList[i].grid(row = i%3, column = i/3)

    ButtonList[i].bind("<Enter>", recolor) 

    i += 1

root.mainloop()
```

This script only recolors the widget that I clicked on and after releasing the button it reacts on `<Enter>` event. How to make the script to react `<Enter>` event on all widgets when I hold the mouse button?

I apologize for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a binding fires, the `widget` attribute will always be set to the widget that is handling the event. To find the widget under the mouse you need to use the method [winfo_containing](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_containing-method).